# Off-diagonal and Diagonal symmetry check, Getting off-diagonal and diagonal element(s) without repetition of a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have this matrix

```
8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3
3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1
1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1
1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1 2
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1 1
1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3 1
1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8 3
3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 8
```

I want to check

1. Off-diagonals are symmetric or not?(in above matrix, these are symmetric)
2. Elements occur in Off-diagonal (without repetition)?-- in above matrix, these elements are 1,2,3
3. Elements in diagonal are symmetric? if yes print element? (like 8 in above matrix)

Comment: You might get a better response if you ever accepted an answer.

Comment: @nograpes how can i accept the answer if it has not required information?

Comment: I noticed that you checked off some answers. That is great. Now try typing `symmetric matrix r` into Google. You will find the function that tests if a matrix is symmetric in R.

Comment: What do you mean by "Elements occur in Off-diagonal (without repetition)"?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I suspect that he means he wants the unique values among the values not in the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# 1
all(mat == t(mat))
[1] TRUE

# 2
unique(mat[upper.tri(mat) | lower.tri(mat)])
[1] 3 1 2

# 3
if(length(unique(diag(mat))) == 1) print(diag(mat)[1])
[1] 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mat <- as.matrix(read.table('abbas.txt'))
isSymmetric(unname(mat))
```

'Note that a matrix is only symmetric if its 'rownames' and 'colnames' are identical.'

```
unique(mat[lower.tri(mat)])

all(diag(mat) == rev(diag(mat)))
# I assume you mean the diagonal is symmetric when its reverse is the same with itself.
```

Comment: `isSymmetric(mat)` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: I had the same issue too. After I change colnames to `NULL`, it returns True.

Comment: I suppose this behavior is not intended. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: In the help manual of `isSymmetirc`, they mentioned 'Note that a matrix is only symmetric if its 'rownames' and
     'colnames' are identical.'

Comment: Right, it's always a good idea to read the documentation... The easiest way could be `isSymmetric(unname(mat))`.